# ggsave doesn't save plots

Tags: r, ggsave

I have been using ggsave for years with no problem. But now it suddenly stopped saving plots. It saves an empty png.
Here's an example (very primitive to show that the problem is not in the plot itself):

```
col2=brewer.pal(n=11, name = "Spectral")
barplot((1:11), col=col2)
ggsave("plot1.png")
```

The plot appears in Rstudio but not in the saved figure.
I recently updated Rstudio ("Ghost Orchid" Release (077589bc, 2021-09-20)) and R (4.1.1 (2021-08-10) -- "Kick Things").
What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: `barplot` is not a ggplot function. That's a base R plotting function. Base R plotting functions do no interact with `ggsave`. So either use a ggplot function or [save the base R way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144118/how-to-save-a-plot-as-image-on-the-disk)

Comment: well, ok, in reality I used pheatmap. The result was the same.

Comment: `pheatmap` is also not a gpplot function. If you are not calling `ggplot()`, then changes are good you're not using ggplot. You should be able to shave `pheatmap` images using the base R method. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051525/how-to-draw-pheatmap-plot-to-screen-and-also-save-to-file

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks very useful!